# Double-clicking a .sln file always opens in VS2019, even though the version is set to 17.x

Tags: visual-studio

I have both VS2019 and VS2022 installed on my machine, and have recently been switching to using the latter for all development.

However, I have noticed that double-clicking a .sln file will always open it in VS2019, even if the file was saved from VS2022. This even happens if the solution was created in VS2022.

[This answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/619989/upgrading-sln-to-open-with-visual-studio-2022-comm.html), backed up by the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2022) suggests that this should not happen.

For example, here is one solution file...

```vb
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.0.32014.148
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyProject", "MyProject\MyProject.csproj", "{75AE5AA2-EEF8-4E98-89D6-49C5D473ACEE}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {75AE5AA2-EEF8-4E98-89D6-49C5D473ACEE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {75AE5AA2-EEF8-4E98-89D6-49C5D473ACEE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {75AE5AA2-EEF8-4E98-89D6-49C5D473ACEE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {75AE5AA2-EEF8-4E98-89D6-49C5D473ACEE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {7837DB11-2301-444C-AEE9-FFE4FED0240B}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

As you can see, the VS version is set to 17.x, so should open in VS2022, not VS2019 (which is version 16.11.1 on my PC).

I tried setting the `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` to be `17.0.0`, but all that did was open it in VS2019 and throw up an error saying the solution needed a newer version of VS! Not very helpful.

Anyone any idea why these .sln files open in VS2019 instead of VS2022? Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @FernandoGómez Nope, very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue and noticed that the file is associated with Visual Studio 2019 instead of Visual Studio Version Selector. I changed the "Open With" association to Visual Studio Version Selector, and these now open for me with VS 2022.